# Text in 3D view linked to an object

Tags: python, 3d-view

I'm looking for a way to display 2D text based on an object's position.

I'm not an expert in blender python, so I couldn't figure out by myself how the Measureit Addon does it. It's very similar to what I want.

So far, I've tried the **blf** drawing functions and the **view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d** but the text doesn't show in the correct position.

Here is my code right now:

```
import bpy
import bpy_extras
import blf 

region = bpy.context.region
rv3d = bpy.context.screen.areas[0].spaces[0].region_3d
coord = bpy.context.active_object.location

pos = bpy_extras.view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d(region, rv3d, coord)

font_info = {
    "font_id": 0,
    "handler": None,
}


def init():
   
    import os
    # Create a new font object, use external ttf file.
    font_path = bpy.path.abspath('//Zeyada.ttf')
    # Store the font indice - to use later.
    if os.path.exists(font_path):
        font_info["font_id"] = blf.load(font_path)
    else:
        # Default font.
        font_info["font_id"] = 0

    # set the font drawing routine to run every frame
    font_info["handler"] = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(
        draw_callback_px, (None, None), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')


def draw_callback_px(self, context):
  
    # BLF drawing routine
    font_id = font_info["font_id"]
    blf.position(font_id, pos[0], pos[1], 0)
    blf.size(font_id, 50, 72)
    blf.draw(font_id, "Hello World")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
```

Any help in solving this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Probably your region and rv3d are not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select a object, run the script. It will display a blf text near the object.

```
#blender 2.92, viewport object mode
import bpy
from blf import position as blfpos   #import the function can improve the performance
from blf import size as blfsize
from blf import draw as blfdraw

import numpy as np
from mathutils import Vector
from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import location_3d_to_region_2d as vec_3d_2d   # a function use for 3dspace(xyz) to viewport region(xy)

font_id = 0
blf_vec = [0, 0, 0]
tx = ""

def draw_blf():
    blfpos(font_id, *blf_vec)
    blfsize(font_id, 50, 72)
    blfdraw(font_id, tx)

def view3d_find( return_area = False ):     # function use for return region, rv3d
    # returns first 3d view, normally we get from context
    for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            v3d = area.spaces[0]
            rv3d = v3d.region_3d
            for region in area.regions:
                if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                    if return_area: return region, rv3d, v3d, area
                    return region, rv3d, v3d
    return None, None

oj = bpy.context.object
tx = oj.name

region, rv3d, v3d = view3d_find()
vec = vec_3d_2d(region, rv3d, oj.location)
print(vec)
blf_vec[0], blf_vec[1] = vec[0], vec[1]

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_blf, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')

#need refresh the screen manually: click the object in viewport
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly, I can see what was wrong with my code now. 

I have noticed that the Meassureit Add-on preserves text linked to the object even when the perspective changes or the 3D Viewport is scaled. I think it is running modal. But I'm not sure how to update location in real-time.

Comment: you can do a operator in {'PASS_THROUGH'} to update the location in real time.

Answer (score 1):

So the final result was a modal operator the {'PASS_THROUGH'} return, as suggested. I'm posting the real-time text update operator in case it helps.

```
import bpy
import bgl
import blf
from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import location_3d_to_region_2d as vec_3d_2d


def draw_callback_px(self, context):

    font_id = 0  
    
    
    oj = bpy.context.active_object
    v3d = context.space_data
    rv3d = v3d.region_3d
    region = bpy.context.region

    vec = vec_3d_2d(region, rv3d, oj.location)
    x = vec[0]
    y = vec[1]
    
    
    
    # draw function
    blf.position(font_id, x, y, 0)
    blf.size(font_id, 20, 72)
    blf.draw(font_id, 'Text')


class ModalDrawText(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Text linked to an object"""
    bl_idname = "view3d.modal_text"
    bl_label = "Show text in 3D Viewport next to the active object"

    def modal(self, context, event):
        context.area.tag_redraw()

        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            
            args = (self, context)
            
            self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "View3D not found, cannot run operator")
            return {'CANCELLED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalDrawText)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalDrawText)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```