# Incorrect display of the drawn text on the screen

Tags: python, gpu

I'm trying to draw text in 3d space, but it draws in wrong coordinates and not directed at the screen. As from here [Text in 3D view linked to an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258013/text-in-3d-view-linked-to-an-object). It work correctly with modal, but did not with this class.
How it look:
[image]

How it needed:

[image]

```
import bpy
import blf

from mathutils import Vector
from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import location_3d_to_region_2d

def view3d_find( return_area = False ):
    for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            v3d = area.spaces[0]
            rv3d = v3d.region_3d
            for region in area.regions:
                if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                    if return_area: return region, rv3d, v3d, area
                    return region, rv3d, v3d
    return None, None

class DrawingClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(self.draw_text, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')
    
    def draw_text(self):
        font_id = 0    
      
        obj = bpy.context.active_object
#        v3d = bpy.context.space_data
#        rv3d = v3d.region_3d
#        region = bpy.context.region

        region, rv3d, v3d = view3d_find()
        
        pos = location_3d_to_region_2d(region, rv3d, obj.location)
        pos_x = pos[0]
        pos_y = pos[1]   
        
        # draw function
        blf.position(font_id, pos_x, pos_y, 0)
        blf.size(font_id, 20)
        blf.draw(font_id, obj.name)

    def remove_handle(self):
        bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self.handle, 'WINDOW')

# to draw           
dns = bpy.app.driver_namespace
dns["dc"] = DrawingClass()

# to remove
dns = bpy.app.driver_namespace
dc = dns.get("dc")
dc.remove_handle()
```

Comment: The text is drawn in 3D space, not 2D. You can use `pos = obj.location` I think

Comment: Hello, it did not help. It draws text near the object but did not turned to the screen

Comment: `blf.position(font_id, pos_x, pos_y, 0)` change to `blf.position(font_id, *obj.location)`  and `blf.size(font_id, 20)` change to `blf.size(font_id, 20, 72)`. If you want display 2D, `'POST_VIEW'` change to `'POST_PIXEL'`

Comment: X Y, did not help also. dpi 72 is deprecated now.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question a bit (to add you want to draw in 2D instead of 3D) and add a schema of how you'd like it to look like.

Comment: Updated question. Added how it look with modal

Comment: X Y, yes! Thank you. It need to update only one word 'POST_VIEW' to 'POST_PIXEL'

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [X Y](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/109459/x-y), all I had to do was replace 'POST_VIEW' to 'POST_PIXEL'.
Updated code:

```
import bpy
import blf

from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import location_3d_to_region_2d

class DrawingClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(self.draw_text, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
    
    def draw_text(self):
        font_id = 0    
      
        obj = bpy.context.active_object
        v3d = bpy.context.space_data
        rv3d = v3d.region_3d
        region = bpy.context.region
        
        pos = location_3d_to_region_2d(region, rv3d, obj.location)
        pos_x = pos[0]
        pos_y = pos[1]   
        
        # draw function
        blf.position(font_id, pos_x, pos_y, 0)
        blf.size(font_id, 20)
        blf.draw(font_id, obj.name)

    def remove_handle(self):
        bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self.handle, 'WINDOW')

# to draw           
dns = bpy.app.driver_namespace
dns["dc"] = DrawingClass()

# to remove
dns = bpy.app.driver_namespace
dc = dns.get("dc")
dc.remove_handle()
```